# Converting timestamp to date ONLY

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timestamp

How to convert timestamp to datetime in c#, but only want the date not included the hour minutes and seconds?

by using this code i have full datetime:

```
double timestamp = Convert.ToDouble(timestamp.Text);
System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp);
lblDate.Text = dateTime.ToString(); //Latest Timestamp
```

just because I just want the date only I remove

```
dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp);
```

and change this line

```
System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

to:

```
System.DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
```

then the result that i got for date is not correct

Comment: You can also use [`"d"` standard format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just date part you can use [DateTime.ToShortDateString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [DateTime.ToLongDateString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
lblDate.Text = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
```

You can also use [Standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) DateTime format string. E.g.

```
lblDate.Text = dateTime.ToString("d"); // same as above
lblDate.Text = dateTime.ToString("D"); // same as ToLongDateString
lblDate.Text = dateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(timestamp.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

After that convert your datetime in date format

if your datetime containing variable is dateTime

so convert its values as

string StrDate=dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

finaly u will get only date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format